# Rewrite Generic URLs into real URLs on Google Analytics

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, google-analytics, replace

I have an iPhone app for a forum which also has a limited Google Analytics reporting.

This app reports the page views in following form:

```
/forum/67
/thread/29036
etc...
```

The numbers above represent forum and thread ID's

I am trying to set an Advanced filter, which will rewrite/report the page views as following form:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum-67.html

http://www.mysite.com/thread-29036.html
```

Can someone please assist me in creating an Advanced Google Analytics filter which will enable me to see URL's so they can be live and send to correct page.

Obviously there will be a need for some `RegExp` matches, but I cannot get around it.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck!

Comment: You should try [WebmastersSE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) since it's not a programming question.

Comment: I posted it there too, but no replies so far.   http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/rewrite-generic-urls-into-real-urls-on-google-analytics